# My Ajax call returns js.erb file as the response in the browser. How do I make it return json contents, but also execute the js.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax, response

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and trying out an application. My application does Ajax calls correctly, but the response is shown as a js.erb file in the browser. How do I show a json response while executing the js.erb file? Is it possible or is there a better way?

Thank you.

My Controller File

```
def new
  @department = Department.new
  # respond_to do |format|
  #   format.html
  #   format.json {render json: @department}
  # end
end

def create
  @departments = Department.all
  @department = Department.create(department_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {render json: @department}
  end
end
```

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfyT9.png)

My Form Partial

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <%= form_for @department, remote: true, data: {type: :json} do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h2> Department: </h2>
    <ul class="errors"></ul>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title, class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body, class: "control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary .departmentCreate" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

[Form.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FFQa.png)

My Json Response if I keep format.js {render json: @department}
[Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtgiJ.png)

My Response if I remove render json from controller:
[JS response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or1JX.png)

My new.js.erb File

```
$("#department-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'departments/new') %>")
$("#department-modal").modal("show")
```

My _new.html.erb partial :

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

My create.js.erb file:

```
<%= render 'save' %>
```

My _save.js.erb partial:

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @department.errors.any? %>
  <% @department.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
<% end %>
<% else %>
  $(".department-index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'departments/index') %>")
  $("#department-modal").modal("hide")
```

While rendering the json response in browser, the js.erb file doesn't execute. How can I show json response in browser while js.erb file executes? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Could you add your code to the question as text instead of image?

Comment: Hey, I've added the code snippets.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to respond with. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've updated the question.

Comment: What does your js.erb template contain?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've updated the question with the snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I show json response in browser while js.erb file executes?
>   Thank you :)

If I understood correctly what you are asking, the answer is you can't. Your response's `Content-Type` will be either an `application/json` or an `application/javascript`.

The browser will use this header to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your JavaScript is not executing is because you have a block present in your controller that handles the response. So the code will never reach your JavaScript file.

Change the line:

```
format.js { render json: @department }
```

to:

```
format.js
```

This will tell Rails that you accept JavaScript request, and since no block is specified the template in "app/views/departments/create.js.erb" is used.

If you don't want to render the default template you can specify it in the block like so:

```
format.js { render: :new } # renders app/views/departments/new.js.erb
```

or:

```
format.js { render: 'some/path' } # renders app/views/some/path.js.erb
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Now json response is not shown in the browser. It just shows the whole create.js.erb file in the browser response. What I actually want is to show the json, but also execute the js.erb file.

Comment: One request can only have one response. If you want the JS file to be executed this is the way to go. If you also want to do something with the JSON you'll have to do that inside your JS file. eg. `$('#some-element').html('<%= j render(json: @department) %>')`. (`j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested rendering of `js.erb` direct render template from controller with full path. assuming full path of `_save.js.erb` is `departments/save`
Also `@departments` should be calculated after create new department so that newly created record will be added with `@departments`

```
def create
  @department = Department.create(department_params)
  @departments = Department.all
  render template: 'departments/save'
end
```

Its always a good practice to pass local variables with partial:_

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @department.errors.any? %>
  <% @department.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
<% end %>
<% else %>
  $(".department-index").html("<%= j render 'departments/index', departments: @departments) %>")
  $("#department-modal").modal("hide")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render both as such, but you can render the partial on the server side, and **store the result in the JSON**. On the client side, you can process JSON, and extract and use the rendered HTML snippet in JS code.

Syntax in Jbuilder for rendering a partial :

`json.some_key json.partial! 'my_partial.js.erb'`

So the stack is something like..

Controller

```rb
# Render the JSON partial in views

respond_to do |format|
    format.json {}
end
```

**View** - controller action will call default json builder for action  e.g `views/departments/new.json.jbuilder`

In here render any original JSON you wanted, like @department, but also render the required JS partial and store it in the JSON

```
json.department @department


json.department_form json.partial! 'new.js.erb'
```

Then in the client code that receives the JSON, for example as `data`, the partial will be present under key **department_form**, and you can assign the rendered form, to an html placeholder element in your original view

```
     //... ajax call to your controller#action
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
                $("#department_form_placeholder").html(data['department_form'])
```

Answer (score 0):

pass type: :script, if you want to execute script on the browser.
In case change your form tag like this:

```html
pass type: :script, if you want to execute script on the browser.
In case change your form tag like this:

<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <%= form_for @department, remote: true, data: {type: :script} do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h2> Department: </h2>
    <ul class="errors"></ul>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title, class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body, class: "control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary .departmentCreate" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @department.errors.any? %>
  <% @department.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
<% end %>
<% else %>
  $(".department-index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'departments/index') %>")
  $("#department-modal").modal("hide")
```